# do.call() isnt appending list of dataframes correctly. any idea why?

Tags: r, do.call

I'm downloading a abunch of PiT datasets, and trying to automate their combination into a single time series dataframe (master_df)

```
temp <- tempfile()
testing <- download.file("https://data.sa.gov.au/data/dataset/3ba1c4dd-e52f-4c28-858a-21284c3ee458/resource/c78fc6da-baa4-47cc-b4df-a97f452bbf9a/download/ken01_p.zip",temp)

filenames<-unzip(temp,list=TRUE)[,1]

#only want csvs
filenames<-filenames[str_detect(filenames,".csv")] 

dfnames = list()

for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
  conn<-unz(temp, filenames[i])
  
  #name files in loop
  filename <- sprintf("df_%s",filenames[i] %>% 
                              str_replace("KEN01_p/KEN01p_1hr","") %>%
                              str_replace(".csv",""))
  
   #  list of filenames
  dfnames[[i]] <- filename
  
  assign(filename, read.csv(conn)) 
}

master_df <-  do.call(rbind, dfnames)

unlink(temp)

class(master_df)
class(df_201912)
```

> class(master_df)
> [1] "matrix"
> class(df_201912)
> [1] "data.frame"

the loop is sucessfully reading all the datasets, and renaming them as df_yyyymm, but do.call rbind is just producing a list of data names.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `assign` since it writes all the dataframes to global environment which is not required. You can combine all the dataframes in one using `lapply`, also some of the dataframes have different column names so it may be better to use `map_df` that would combine them into one dataframes anyway by appending `NA` values.

```
purrr::map_df(filenames, function(x) {
  read.csv(unz(temp, x))  
}) -> master_df

master_df
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in the code is assignment of the `list` element with filename instead of the value

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
  conn<-unz(temp, filenames[i])
  
  #name files in loop
  filename <- sprintf("df_%s",filenames[i] %>% 
                              str_replace("KEN01_p/KEN01p_1hr","") %>%
                              str_replace(".csv",""))
  
   #  list of filenames
  dfnames[[i]] <- read.csv(conn) ###
  
  #assign(filename, read.csv(conn)) 
}
```

Also, there are some `list` elements with different names, thus `rbind` wouldn't work, we can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
out <- rbindlist(dfnames, fill = TRUE) dim(out)
[1] 44544     6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to download a *zip* file, unpack it and read all *csv* files into one large dataset:

```
temp <- tempfile()
testing <- download.file(
    "https://data.sa.gov.au/data/dataset/3ba1c4dd-e52f-4c28-858a-21284c3ee458/resource/c78fc6da-baa4-47cc-b4df-a97f452bbf9a/download/ken01_p.zip",
    temp)

filenames <- unzip(temp, list = FALSE)

library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # piping used to improve readability

master_df <- lapply(filenames, fread) %>% 
  set_names(filenames %>% basename() %>% stringr::str_remove_all("^KEN01p_1hr|\\.csv$")) %>% 
  rbindlist(fill = TRUE, idcol = TRUE)


master_df
```

> ```
>           .id        Date/Time PM10 TEOM ug/m3 PM2.5 TEOM ug/m3 Temperature Deg C Barometric Pressure atm PM10 BAM ug/m3
>     1: 201501   1/01/2015 1:00            18.2               NA              16.8                   0.986             NA
>     2: 201501   1/01/2015 2:00            20.3               NA              15.9                   0.985             NA
>     3: 201501   1/01/2015 3:00            27.9               NA              15.1                   0.985             NA
>     4: 201501   1/01/2015 4:00            23.6               NA              16.9                   0.984             NA
>     5: 201501   1/01/2015 5:00            15.8               NA              19.7                   0.984             NA
>    ---                                                                                                                  
> 44540: 201912 31/12/2019 20:00              NA               NA              19.4                      NA             14
> 44541: 201912 31/12/2019 21:00              NA               NA              18.0                      NA             14
> 44542: 201912 31/12/2019 22:00              NA               NA              16.7                      NA             19
> 44543: 201912 31/12/2019 23:00              NA               NA              15.8                      NA             11
> 44544: 201912   1/01/2020 0:00              NA               NA              15.3                      NA             12
> ```

Note that I have changed the `list` parameter in

```
filenames <- unzip(temp, list = FALSE)
```

to `FALSE`. This unpacks the *zip* file into a subdirectory named `KEN01_p`. After unpacking, the subdirectory contains 61 *csv* files with 1.5 MBytes in total.

Also note that the `.id` column in `master_df` indicates the source of each row